# In Java what is the difference between "invoke a constructor" and "execute a constructor"?

Tags: java

I really don't have an example, but I get confused between the two terms, as sometimes one is used and sometimes the other is used.

When a constructor is "invoked" is it also "executed"? Are they interchangeable?

Also, the word "call" is used a lot, as in "call a constructor".

And then there is "constructor completes".

I'm sure I'm not alone in my confusion, so an explanation with an example would be very helpful for many of us newbies trying to make sense of all of the terms.

I am using the Bates and Sierra book and here is the section that got me thinking about it:

"But what really happens when you say new Horse() ?
(Assume Horse extends Animal and Animal extends Object.)
1. Horse constructor is invoked. Every constructor invokes the constructor
of its superclass with an (implicit) call to super(), unless the constructor
invokes an overloaded constructor of the same class (more on that in a
minute).
2. Animal constructor is invoked (Animal is the superclass of Horse).
3. Object constructor is invoked (Object is the ultimate superclass of all
classes, so class Animal extends Object even though you don't actually
type "extends Object" into the Animal class declaration. It's implicit.) At
this point we're on the top of the stack.
4. Object instance variables are given their explicit values. By explicit values,
we mean values that are assigned at the time the variables are declared,
like "int x = 27", where "27" is the explicit value (as opposed to the
default value) of the instance variable.
5. Object constructor completes.
6. Animal instance variables are given their explicit values (if any).
7. Animal constructor completes."

Comment: They all mean the same thing. You left out a few ;-)

Comment: invoke, call, execute are the same thing in this context, even though I'd tend to say that "execute" is the most confusing of them all. I would rather use it in the context of "program execution".

Comment: Don't forget "create an instance/object", "instantiate a class" (although those do not specify which constructor was used, if several were available)

Answer (score 4):

The terms "invoke", "execute", and "call" mean the same thing and are interchangeable. What is meant by "constructor completes" is that the constructor finishes its invocation, or execution, or call, whatever your prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they all mean the same thing. You might want to survey information on the topic from a few different sources whenever a textbook gets confusing. A very good place to look would be the official Java Tutorials, e.g. on [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), which always has plenty of simple examples.

Technically, you "call"/"invoke" a method, it then gets "executed" and then "completes". And technically, if you have [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) there is an additional step "lookup which method should really be executed" between the "call"/"invoke" and "executed" steps.

Answer (score 1):

"Invoke" is the same as "call" is the same as "execute", when talking about constructors or any other method.

A constructor is just another method, albeit a special one.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to understand is by giving a sample of code:

```
class Animal {

    public Animal(){}

}

class Horse extends Animal {

    public Horse(){
        super();//this line will be added by the compiler even if you didn't type it.
    }

    public Horse(String name){
        this(); //this line will call the default constructor.
    }

}
```

invoking the constructor is creating an instance from its class:

```
Horse horse = new Horse();
```

calling the constructor is done by:

```
super();//in our case it will call Animal constructor
```

or

```
this();//this will call the default constructor of the same class.
```

and you execute the constructor by calling or invoking it.

Comment: Okay, good, it all makes sense. But what about when there are multiple constructors, some taking parameters and some not, which ones get called first? I know a constructor's super constructor gets called first but what about the other constructors in the superconstructor's class? Do they need to  be called by constructor's that have the same number of arguments? Confused about this too. I'll post an example if I can find one.

Comment: the constructor that is going to be called depends on the code you write, if you create an object of class Horse like this: 
Horse h1 = new Horse("name");
because we have call to the default constructor this(); it will call the first constructor that has no parameters, and the first constructor will call the super, which is Animal constructor, and now the interesting part, Animal constructor will be the first to complete, then the first constructor in class Horse, and finally the constructor that you invoked Horse(String name);

Comment: So if Animal has several constructors, they don't necessarily all have to be invoked? Just the one that is called by the subclass constructor?

Comment: That's right, just the one you call by subclass, and if the one you call does not contain this() call

Comment: I recommend you a book, that I found very helpful and helped me pass my first Java certification. http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060

Comment: Wonderful! Great answers you gave me! Thank you, I will definitely look the book up.

Answer (score -2):

Iam pretty sure they are the same  once the object is created or made the constructor is automatically called or invoked or indeed executed.

Comment: The constructor 'makes' the object. You're just adding to the confusion.

Comment: i didnt say that if you read my answer. i said  once the object is created or made the constructor is automatically called!

Comment: of course hes not listening  to me now. ha ha . also booourns for the downvote.